# multimarkers on google map using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

This the link of my code visit https://www.dropbox.com/s/1j0qc2uyp8vm9xj/map_user.php, this code is not working. I used JSON to get the array of data in mysql then echo it to javascript but when I try to run it I only see a gray map. Can anyone help me?

```
<?php
include('lock.php');
include('function/query.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>USER MAPS AND UPDATES</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <?php
  $x = 0;
  $query  = "SELECT lat,lng FROM messages WHERE uid_fk='1'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     $data[$x] = array("lat" => $row['lat'], "lng" => $row['lng']);
     $x++;
   }
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var markers = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>

function initializeMaps() {
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
    var marker, i;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        bounds.extend(pos);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
initializeMaps();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use the inspector/developer tools in your browser to check for javascript errors (In Chrome, press F12, look for red Cross in bottom right corner, click on it to see errors). If you put the specific error here you will get better help.

Comment: I already fix this error ^^ thanks for your help guys,